# Why are any two initial objects of a category equivalent?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

> Why are any two initial objects of a category equivalent?

By definition:

If $A,B$ are initial objects of a category $C$, then for each $X \in \text{obj } C$, there exists a unique morphisms $f : A \rightarrow X, g : B \rightarrow X$.

How can these be equivalent?  This seems to just indicate that each $A$ and $B$ have their own set of maps.

Comment: It's the uniqueness of the morphism that forces the isomorphism between A and B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Since $A$ is initial, there is a unique map $A \to B$.
- Since $B$ is initial, there is a unique map $B \to A$.

Furthermore, they are inverses; the products have to be identities because

- Since $A$ is initial, there is a unique map $A \to A$.
- Since $B$ is initial, there is a unique map $B \to B$.

Answer (score 2):

Any two initial objects are *isomorphic*, even though they may not literally be equal.

Proof: Call them $A$ and $A'$. By assumption, there are unique morphisms $a: A \to A'$, $a': A' \to A$. Then $aa': A' \to A'$ has to be $1_{A'}$, because $A'$ is initial. Similarly $a'a = 1_A$. Thus $A \cong A'$.

For example, in the category of sets, all singleton sets are final objects (dual to initial); they are all isomorphic as sets, even though not all equal.